# TypeError while counting number of pages in multiple PDF files within a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to count the number of Pages of various PDF files within a drectory but I am stuck with an error

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
import re
import os

rxcountpages = re.compile(r"$\s*/Type\s*/Page[/\s]", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

def countPages(filename):
    data = file(filename,"rb").read()
    return len(rxcountpages.findall(data))

if __name__=="__main__":
    parent = "/Users/ss/Desktop/shared/pdf"
    for f in os.listdir(parent):
        if f.endswith('.pdf'):
            print f
            print "Number of pages in PDF File:", countPages(f)
```

Not sure how to get rid of the error. I tried referencing some other stackoverflow QA pages but couldn't get it working.

Full traceback:

> runfile('/Users/ss/untitled0.py', wdir='/Users/ss')  Number of pages
>   in PDF File:Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/Users/ss/untitled0.py', wdir='/Users/ss')
>
> File
>   "/Users/ss/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 866, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "/Users/ss/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 94, in execfile
>       builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
>
> File "/Users/ss/untitled0.py", line 22, in 
>       print "Number of pages in PDF File:", countPages(f)
>
> File "/Users/ss/untitled0.py", line 15, in countPages
>       data = file(filename,"rb").read()
>
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: You have redefined some variable (perhaps `len` or `countPages`) as a string. Please post the full error message including traceback to help us pinpoint where.

Comment: Is that all of your code?

Comment: Yup thats the complete code

Comment: It's `file` you've defined as a string somewhere. You should be using `open()` rather than the `file` constructor anyway.